# "Sequentially compactness" of compact Riemann surface

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces

I'm in trouble show that for any sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in a compact Riemann surface, there exist a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k}\}_k$ of $\{x_n\}_n$, a chart $(U,\varphi)$ and an $x\in U$ such that the sequence $\{\varphi (x_{n_k})\}_k$ converges to $\varphi(x)$.

Any help?

Comment: This is a fact from point-set topology. The fact it's a Riemann surface isn't really relevant beyond letting you use that the space is metrizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Riemann surface is compact, you can cover it by finitely many charts $(U_i,\varphi_i)$, each of whose closures is compact. By the pigeonhole principle, find a chart $(U_{i_0},\varphi_{i_0})$ such that for infinitely many $n_k$, $x_{n_k}\in U_{i_0}$. Can you finish the proof from here?

The proof should make it clear that this is really not a proper statement about Riemann surfaces *per se*, since we have no use for the fact that the transition maps $\varphi_{UV}:\varphi_U(U)\longrightarrow\varphi_V(V)$ are holomorphic. It is at best a statement about compact and locally Euclidean topological spaces as this answer suggests.

Comment: I can understand it. But I don't know what the next action is.

Comment: @Ichiko: I updated my answer: transfer the subsequence to a compact subset of the complex plane using $\varphi_{i_0}$, and finish the proof from there.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.